# Android Find the position of touched TextView in a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a `TableLayout` with 60 `TextViews` and i need to recognize witch `TextViews` the user touch for change their text and background color.
The problem is that i save in a sqlite database the inputed data and i don't know how load the content inside `TableView` when the user launch the app.
I try with ids saved in the database but it's not good.
How can i do that?
Any idea?

If the user touch the `TextView` in a position 1:1 Row:Column how can i know this?
If i know Row:Column in `onCreate` method i can insert to `TableView` the new changed `TextViews`

Some xml of the TableLayout:

```
<TableRow
                android:id="@+id/prima_riga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat11"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text=""/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat12"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat13"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat14"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat15"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat16"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
            </TableRow>
```

With the method addMateria i change text and background of the TextViews.

Comment: did you tried using onClickListener or onTouchListener on the textviews ?
If you want to know which textview is clicked then you can use them and get the desired results.

Comment: Dario, you have to handle 60 onClick methods on textviews. In this case I HIGHLY recommend you to use GridView, ListView or RecyclerView. Dario, piuttosto che usare 60 textview in cui devi gestire 60 onClick, usa una gridview o una listview!

Comment: @Darkie no i don't, but now i try with this. They return the position??

Comment: @Fondesa Ok i try with the GridView, ListView or RecyclerView. Fondesa, ti ringrazio per la duplice risposta italo/inglese.
Sono nuovo con Android quindi inesperto, proverò i layout che mi hai suggerito

Comment: @Dario ti consiglio di partire con ListView e GridView e un ArrayAdapter per fare le cose gradualmente, poi spostati su un ViewHolder pattern invece di una getView quando hai capito le cose fino in fondo. Infine, ti consiglio le RecyclerView, sono relativamente nuove, le migliori dal punto di vista della gestione della memoria, ma sono più difficili delle due precedenti da implementare. Buon coding.

Comment: @Fondesa Ora mi documento per bene sulle cose che hai menzionato.
Nel caso avessi problemi riscrivo!
Grazie anche a te

Answer (score 0):

You know which textView you clicked from the method:

```
 public void onClick(View v)
   {
        // do something with the textView

        TextView textView = (TextView) v;
        var tag = textView.getTag();

        // do something with the tag if needed
   }
```

If you need to place some information in the textView, just use setTag() method:

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h1);
if(textView1) != null
textView1.setTag("whatever object you need");
```

EDIT: as @Fondesa said, if you have so many textViews in your layout, it would be better to use a listview/gridview, but the idea remains the same for textView click in you adapter. Or you could use click directly from list items.

Comment: i need to set the Tag or it's dafault?
Any TextView have a tag? Or i must set the Tag before use the getTag()?

Comment: By default controls do not have any tag. You use seTag() only if you need some information regarding the specific textView that you would like to use onClick.

Comment: For example, if you want to set the name of an object from the database, you use setText, but it you want to keep the whole database object, you put it in the textView's tag.

Comment: So when i Click to some TextView and i want save which textview, i can set a Tag from that TextViews so i can find it into a layout. Right?

Comment: If I understand correcly what you want to do, in a layout, you can find a textview by its id. If you want to save which ones you clicked, you can save the ids, and then just use findViewById.

Comment: No i do that, if you want i can add some java code.
My problem is this:
I have a database with which textviews are changed, and i save the text, the backgroundcolor and id.
The problem is that i want save the coordinates not the ids, if i need to generate another table with the same data i can't use the id, because the id that i save are referred to the "input" table, but if i have the coordinates i can change every table with the same data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74853/discussion-between-dario-and-a-b).